# Ansible REST API Dashboard

Tags: rest, ansible, dashboard

I am trying to figure out the best way to display information from a bunch of servers after an ansible command runs on a bunch of servers; more specifically, I am looking to get status information from processes from n amount of servers and display that information in some dashboard. I was thinking of having a nodejs app (REST API) on the controller that ansible would POST to after it got it's data from all the servers. I am not sure where to start and curious if someone has a working example of this. How would one deal with failures as well? I know Tower probably provides this out of the box but looking to do this with the core edition.

Answer (score 0):

Write a callback plugin to process required events and POST when necessary.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/berlic/devopsdays-ansible/blob/b7440040191fd769adca18d67670353baf493cec/callback_plugins/notify_me.py) of `v2_playbook_on_stats` processing to show OS popup notification about success/failure.

You can simply POST the whole `stats` object to your service and draw green/red labels for your servers.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot. Now it looks like that example callback will iterate all the hosts so how does that work when you have a playbook and a task iterating all the hosts?

Comment: `v2_playbook_on_stats` fires only once when playbook is finished (I just iterate over all hosts involved and check status of each).